# Microsoft Graph - find and/or validate shared mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm working on an app that uses the Microsoft Graph API to send emails via a user's email account, by sending a `POST` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail` with a base64-encoded MIME message. I want to be able to allow users to send mail from a [shared mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/admin/email/about-shared-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide). This works in my dev environment with a shared mailbox that I have access to, if I hard-code the "From" field of the message to the shared mailbox address.

My question is: how do I allow users to select a shared mailbox to use when setting up the app? Ideally I'd like to present them with a drop-down list of mailboxes they can access, but there doesn't seem to be any way to find these using the Graph API (although I did spot this [feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-manage-shared-mailbox-access/idi-p/2432951)). Failing that, is there a way that I can verify that an email address entered by a user is one they are authorised to send mail from (without actually attempting to send an email)? Thanks!